# ArgumentError: Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano3

Currently my Rails app is running on Heroku. Now I'm trying to deploy it on a VPS (Ubuntu, trusty tarr), but when I run

```
cap production deploy
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ArgumentError: Missing required arguments: aws_access_key_id, aws_secret_access_key
```

I'm using the Carrierwave gem and Fog, to upload images to Amazon S3 storage. I created environment variable on Heroku, but not sure how to do this on a VPS.

Any help is greatly appreciated,

Anthony

Comment: add your deploy.rb file

Comment: how do you mean Serdar, I have a config/deploy.rb file in my app?

Comment: @Toontje Yep, show it to us as part of your question.